Site name is not updated in the Android app

Unknown Site cogsci

It is updated on the edit panel though


Nice catch. I commented here to the SE mod team to let them know. I linked your question there.

Can you let us know if the answer worked out and if yes accept it?

Sorry I was inactivity for the past days. I'm not sure whether I should accept it or not (see the comment below)

I asked our Android dev and he said that logging out of the app and then logging back in should fix it up. Give that a go and please let me know if it's still showing up wrong.

Well it's fixed for me before I had a chance to log out

@Ooker Isn’t caching great? :)
